# Amount of free electrons in a metal

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, solid-state-physics, conductors

How can I calculate the amount of free electrons in a metal?
I search the forum but found nothing
What I want to know is how many electrons can I remove from a metal using photoelectric effect (consider a fully insulated metal)

Comment: As for the removal, you need to consider the capacitance of the metal to then get the voltage you will build up as electrons leave, resulting in it being harder to get the next electron out. There are way more electrons available then you could possibly get out because of the potential build up (see Van de Graaff generator).

Answer (score 1):

As to your second question with sufficient energy and intensity in principle you can get out any number of electrons until the metal evaporates or becomes so highly charged that it suffers Coulomb explosion.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of free electrons in metals, you can use (from Hyperphysics web site):

$$n=\frac{(N_{A})(ρ)}{A}$$

where $N_A$ = Avogadro's numbern (atoms/mole)

$ρ$ = density (kg/m$^3$)

$A$ =  Atomic mass {lg/mole)

$n$ = number of atoms per unit volume $m$^3$, and the number of free electrons for metals like copper which have one free electron per atom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And other metals may have more free electrons per atom.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I think that's what I said. The equation only gives the number of atoms per unit volume. Copper is just given as an example where there is one free electron per atom. One needs to know the number of free electrons per atom.

Comment: there is a calculator here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html   , third chapter. But this means they are there as targets  for the photoelectric effect. not that all can be removed.